# Active Record join, SUM and group_by on votes given

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I'm using rails 4.2 and ruby 2.2

I have the following three models

Entrant (Devise User)

```
Entrant.column_names
=> ["id", "email", "encrypted_password", "reset_password_token", "reset_password_sent_at", "remember_created_at", "sign_in_count", "current_sign_in_at", "last_sign_in_at", "current_sign_in_ip", "last_sign_in_ip", "created_at", "updated_at", "confirmation_token", "confirmed_at", "confirmation_sent_at", "unconfirmed_email", "entrant_name"]

class Entrant < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :entries
   has_many :votes, :through => :entries
end
```

Entry

```
Entry.column_names
 => ["id", "entrant_id", "title_of_work", "price", "created_at", "updated_at", "media_file_name", "media_content_type", "media_file_size", "media_updated_at", "paid", "height", "width", "type_of_media"]

class Entry < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :entrant
    has_many :votes
    has_many :entrants, :through => :votes
end
```

Vote

```
Vote.column_names
=> ["id", "entry_id", "judge_id", "score", "created_at", "updated_at"]

class Vote < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :entry
    belongs_to :judge
end
```

I need a query that will return the following table. I've tried starting with Entrant and joining Votes but nothing has worked.

[image]

The query needs to pull out all entries, and sum the votes.score field and order by votes.score but it also needs to group by entry so that the entries are not duplicated.

This is as close as I have got, but it doesnt work.

```
@entries = Entrant.joins(:entries).joins(:votes).select('entrants.*, entries.*, SUM(votes.score) as total_votes').distinct.group('entrants.id, entries.id, votes.score')
```

Comment: Your models don't seem right.  If Entries and Entrants are really many to many, you should have a join table, yet you seem to have an entrant_id attribute in your Entry table.  Can you explain how these two entities are related?

Comment: Hi Steve, perhaps I've got them setup wrong. An Entrant can have many Entries and thats as simple as it should be.

Comment: OK then in Entry, you want `belongs_to :entrant` instead of `has_many :entrants, :through => :votes`.

Comment: Next Q - in your view (nice mockup btw!), which Entry title do you expect to be shown assuming one line per Entrant?  Or is it one line per Entry (so we could see multiple rows with the same Entrant)?

Comment: In the view it would be one line per entry with all the scores added up for each entry in the Score column. So Entrant One could have three entries in the top 10 for example.

Answer (score 3):

It should be something like:

```
Entry.joins(:entrant).joins(:votes)
                     .group('entries.id')
                     .order('SUM("votes.score")').
                     .pluck(:entrant_name, :title_of_work, 'SUM("votes.score")'),'COUNT("votes.score")')
```

I worked this out in the console with a similar set of relationships I have set up so it may need a bit of tweaking but it should get you pointed in the right direction.  Let me know if you get stuck.